# Angular ui-select, ignore empty item in choices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

Say I have such an array.

```
$scope.countries = [
    {name: 'a'},
    {name: 'b'},
    {notName:'xx'}
 ];
```

I want to use angular ui-select to form a dropdown select. Since the third object doesn't contain 'name', it should not be shown.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jbFDnJZSsGHVnC7Ty0wK?p=preview

But ui-select keeps showing a small empty space. Wonder how I can overcome this.
Appreciates.

Comment: Not used ui-select  before but from playing about with demo it looks like you just have to fill in the placeholder field. Have you tried that? It would be good if you could provide a demo on plunker or jsfiddle.

Comment: @MattHerbstritt Hi, sorry my previous question is a bit misleading, I just updated with plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a custom filter before the search filter like this:

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uotx8d4Rc1YwWj3HksyX?p=preview)

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <p>Selected: {{country.selected}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries| removeBlanks | filter: $select.search ">
      <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.country = {};
  $scope.countries = [
    {name: 'a'},
    {name: 'b'},
    {notName:'xx'}
  ];
  $scope.ignore = {notName:'xx'};
});

app.filter('removeBlanks', function() {
  return function( items) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(!item.hasOwnProperty('notName')){
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });

    console.log('filtered', filtered);
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ng-show`? That might work, I haven't used `ui-select`, but this usually works for me with `ng-repeat`:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="node.dataName as node in flattenData | filter: $select.search" ng-show="node.dataName">
    <span ng-bind-html="node.dataName| highlight: $select.search"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but ng-hide seems also not working in my case :(